# Como ativar 24 horas no Datapicker Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3, datepicker

[image: DataPicker- Bootstrap]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss',
             locale: 'fr,
             use24hours: true       
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
             format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            locale: 'fr,
             use24hours: true       
        });
    });
</script>
```

Use HH maiusculo

Referencia: resposta do @[Benjam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847443/datetimepicker-time-picker-in-24-hour-but-displaying-in-12hr)

Comment: Funcionou... !!

Answer (score 3):

Colocando as referencias de:

***Css***

- [bootstrap.min.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)
- [datetimepicker.css](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css)

***Javascript***

- [jquery.min.hs](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js)
- [bootstrap.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js)
- [moment-with-locales.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js)
- [bootstrap-datetimepicker.js](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js)

formate o formato da hora com **H** em ***maiúsculo***, exemplo:

```
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
```

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({           
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
       locale: 'PT-BR'             
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

***Referencias:***

- [***Bootstrap 3 Datepicker***](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
- [***Bootstrap 3 Datepicker - #Custom Formats***](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-formats)